# Fast join of two big DataTables

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ado.net

I have 2 big DataTables and need to intersect them by the equality of their composite keys - say fields `("Id1", "Id2")` from one table and `("MyId1", "MyId2")` from the other.

I need this to work as fast as possible, so regular LINQ JOIN on data rows isn't the solution. I want to create dictionaries for tables like `<composite_key>/<datarow>` and then intersect their keys, that will speed up the work significally. For composite keys i need to use something like `Tuple` that combines values and make the comparison possible. This works pretty fast, but the problem comes when i try to compare keys like `Tuple<int, int>(1,1)` and `Tuple<short, short>(1,1)` - since type parameters differ, the keys will never be equal. The only option i see now is to pre-convert key fields to their most covering type (like bytes, ints, longs - to long etc) and then compare. Not a nice soluton.
Questions:
1. Is there something similar to Tuple that can compare values of that "similar" types?
2. Is there other fast way to join two data tables?
Thanks!
PS: these key fields are not always a primary key for datatable

Comment: creating a DB view would be much more efficient than doing it in code

Comment: @Shekhar in my app i may have data from variuos sources, not only from SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You can use same type for equality check in Linq. Using widening convertion (short to int) to prevent data lost.

```
var tableA = new List<Tuple<int, int>>() { new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1) };
var tableB = new List<Tuple<short, short>>() { new Tuple<short, short>(1, 1), new Tuple<short, short>(1, 2) };


var queryResult = from a in tableA
                    join b in tableB
                    on a equals new Tuple<int, int>((int)b.Item1, (int)b.Item2)
                    select new { a, b };
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'd like to solve problem in a more common manner, just if i had not only these types